# Motivation for mutiple layers of referencing? - Code Academy JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working through the JavaScript track on CodeAcademy and have encountered a question on Objects II -> Introduction to Objects II -> Private Methods (25/30).  I'm not understanding the motivation behind things pointing to things, that point to other things.  If we are trying to get to the value of a variable why not refer to it more directly?  For example

var d refers to var c
          and
var c refers to var b
          and
var b refers to var a

Why do this rather than referring to var a initially?  Why create variables b, c, and d at all?  Anyway in Private Methods - 25/30 the heart of the matter is below.  *Note - I put the exhaustive/exact code at the very bottom

---

```
**var bankBalance = 7500;**                    // Located within the Person class

 **var returnBalance  = function()**           // Create returnBalance method which returns
       **return bankBalance;**                 //  the bankBalance above                      

t**his.askTeller = function() {**              // Create the askTeller method which calls
       **return returnBalance;**               //  returnBalance method above

**var myBalanceMethod = john.askTeller();**    // create a variable named myBalanceMethod 
                                               // which equals the value for askTeller method above

**var myBalance = myBalanceMethod();**         // create a variable named myBalance which
                                               // equals the value for myBalanceMethod method above

**console.log(myBalance);**                    // logs to the console the value of myBalance
```

---

This all seems like a lot of trouble.  What is the motivation to go through all this trouble instead of a more direct reference to bankBalance?

Below I have included my EXACT code (note - it works just fine I just don't understand to reasoning behind the multiple layers)

```
**function Person(first,last,age) {
   this.firstname = first;
   this.lastname = last;
   this.age = age;
   var bankBalance = 7500;

   var returnBalance = function() {
      return bankBalance;
   };

   // create the new function here
   this.askTeller = function() {
       return returnBalance;
   };
}

var john = new Person('John','Smith',30);
console.log(john.returnBalance);
var myBalanceMethod = john.askTeller();
var myBalance = myBalanceMethod();
console.log(myBalance);**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing something through another name isn't demonstrated properly in the example (which is why *real-world* examples are so necessary and so praised when used).

When we assign a variable to something we already have a reference for, such as:

```
var cc = Components.Classes;
```

we can do it for brevity, such as above. Writing `cc` as opposed to `Components.classes` can make the code a lot clearer and easier to read, as long as the context is clear. Once you start using APIs, the DOM or complex objects, the usefulness of this becomes quite clear. In this case, I can replace all my `Components.Classes` references, such as:

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger;1"];
```

with

```
cc["@mozilla.org/messenger;1"];
```

Much better - especially when you have to chain these:

```
var os = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
```

becomes:

```
var os = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);
```

Now it fits in a single line and is much easier to vgrep/tokenize-with-your-eyes.

Another advantage is assigning, for example, as single definition of a function to two or more objects:

```
function _start() { /* start monitoring */ }
function _stop() { /* stop monitoring */ }

/* ... code ... */

process_observer.start = _start;
process_observer.stop = _stop;

memory_monitor.start = _start;
memory_monitor.stop = _stop;
```

In this example, assuming we've written our `_start` and `_stop` functions to be agnostic of what our object monitors and can fit *any* monitoring object, we can write our function once and *still* assign it to each object separately so we can call `process_observer.start()` instead of `start(process_observer)` which would requite *acting on the object* rather than *having the object act* ( the former might involve exposing data and methods we would otherwise want to keep hidden, to prevent errors and promote clarity - it also might prevent us from using certain design patterns ). These are of course a matter of preference, design approaches and perspective, but **never underestimate readability and clarity in code**. Also, if we change `_start` or `_stop` is changes for all objects that use them, instead of requiring manual changes. *A common usage case is having different implementations for different platforms or browsers and having the proper function assigned to all objects that use it, at initialization, where we detect what where running on.*

Also, you might have noticed I didn't use parenthesis `()` when I assigned my functions to the object owned variables - when you do it like your example:

```
myBalance = myBalanceMethod();
```

you're not assigning `myBalanceMethod` to `myBalance` - you're calling `myBalanceMethod` (because of the `()`) and assigning *it's return value* to `myBalance` - **very big trap**. People trip over this all the time when assigning click handlers in html elements.

*To be honest, as I said in the beginning, the example is terrible - there is no reason write that code that way and, as you've already found out yourself, it makes it harder to understand rather than easier, which is the whole point of aliasing variables and functions and being able to assign them so freely.*